# TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im running some code, and when I do `npm start` I get this error:

```
  throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
  ^
  TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object at Function.use (/bustabit-webserver/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
at Function.<anonymous> (/bustabit- webserver/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Function.use (/bustabit- webserver/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (/bustabit-webserver/server/index.js:93:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Line 92 of server/index.js is

```
app.use('/client_old', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client_old'), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 1000 }));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do  ?

Comment: just make the code to run :/

Comment: It does not look to me as if this line is the problem. First of all the error says it is line `93` but you state that the line you show is line `93`, and `express.static` returns a functions. So what is line `93`?

Comment: What does a
console.log(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client_old'))
output?

Comment: Ill try now, wait one second

Answer (score 0):

**Don't write like this:**
router.use('/', Router);

**write your routes like this:**
router.use('/', ()=> Router);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).